# Error saving new shape file after using over() function R

Tags: r

I am trying to use over function from sp package in R, to add attribute values from a polygon layer to a new column in a point layer and save the resulting layer as a new shape file. All seams to work except the last step to save a new shape file.

```
   library(rgdal)
        library(sp)

    county <- readOGR(dsn=home ,layer="county") # reads in polygon layer with counties
    species <- readOGR(dsn=home, layer="species") # reads point layer with with some species observations

species@data$county <- over(species, county[,1]) # adds according county name to every observation
writeOGR(trans_nh, dsn=home, layer ="nh_maakond", driver="ESRI Shapefile")
```

All steps until the writeOGR command are working fine, but when I try to save a new shape  file (or mapinfo) I get a following error:

```
Error in writeOGR(species, dsn = home, layer = "species_county", driver = "ESRI Shapefile") : 
  Can't convert columns of class: data.frame; column names: county
```

Just in case I add output from str(species) after the over() has been applied

```
     str(species)
Formal class 'SpatialPointsDataFrame' [package "sp"] with 5 slots
  ..@ data       :'data.frame': 3700 obs. of  4 variables:
  .. ..$ LAD_NIMI: Factor w/ 19 levels "Chiroptera sp.",..: 13 1 2 4 6 1 11 1 2 2 ...
  .. ..$ andmed  : Factor w/ 401 levels "Eelisesse","EELIS_II_kat",..: 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 ...
  .. ..$ Andmed_1: Factor w/ 0 levels: NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  .. ..$ county :'data.frame':  3700 obs. of  1 variable:
  .. .. ..$ MNIMI: Factor w/ 15 levels "Harju maakond",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
  ..@ coords.nrs : num(0) 
  ..@ coords     : num [1:3700, 1:2] 397642 397642 400479 401127 401127 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : NULL
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "coords.x1" "coords.x2"
  ..@ bbox       : num [1:2, 1:2] 388929 6381608 738925 6618427
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "coords.x1" "coords.x2"
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "min" "max"
  ..@ proj4string:Formal class 'CRS' [package "sp"] with 1 slots
  .. .. ..@ projargs: chr "+proj=lcc +lat_1=58 +lat_2=59.33333333333334 +lat_0=57.51755393055556 +lon_0=24 +x_0=500000 +y_0=6375000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m "| __truncated__
```

Do have any ideas what may I be doing wrong?
Thanks for your effort!

I played around a bit more and I got i to work with an extra step. As Koekenbakker suggested in a comment the data I was trying to get was somehow added as a data.frame inside the data frame. I added an extra step and lost an argument from the over() function and it did the trick. The code is as follows:
library(rgdal)
            library(sp)

```
    county <- readOGR(dsn=home ,layer="county") # reads in polygon layer with counties
    species <- readOGR(dsn=home, layer="species") # reads point layer with with some species observations

species@data$county <- over(species, count) # adds according county name to every observation
trans_nh@data$county <- trans_nh@data$county$MNIMI # the new step added
    writeOGR(trans_nh, dsn=home, layer ="nh_maakond", driver="ESRI Shapefile")
```

I am not sure if it is supposed to work like that or it's just a workaround. Any way I got it done. Thanks.

Comment: It looks like your `county` data are present not as a vector but as a data.frame within a data frame (`@data`). Try changing your `over()` call, something like `c(county[,1])` or `county$MNIMI`.

Comment: I am not quite understand what you were suggesting, but it got me thinking I found a solution. Thanks.